# What are some ways to make concrete steps look nice and presentable?

Tags: concrete

I have the following concrete steps in my porch that I would like to clean up and tidy. What are some things that I could do myself to make it look nice? Are there any pre made and easy slab fittings I could use or any other alternative or special paint or coating available?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is too broad, being both open-ended and subjective. We're not a discussion forum. I suggest a trip to your local paint or home improvement store to read some labels.

Comment: Forget the steps, it looks like you have some rotten wood under the gutter and the post was replaced because it rotted out?

Comment: What does "nice and presentable" mean? Give us some definitions for what it means to you so we can guide you to an appropriate answer. Otherwise, you'll get what _we_ think is nice, and that may not match up very well.

Answer (score 1):

Floor paint, either one or two component, will hold up and might look better but as mentioned above you should fix the underlying surfaces.